# Can a set of integers be linearly indepedent over rational field $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory

As title says, can a set of integers be linearly independent over rational field $\mathbb{Q}$ or integer ring $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Any integers $a,b$ satisfy the relation $ax+by=0$ with $x=b$, $y=-a$.

Comment: A  set of $1$ integer can be.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $\mathbb{Q}$ as a one-dimensional vector space over itself. Any linearly independent set in one-dimensional vector space must consist of one nonzero element.